# Using the URLconf defined in tango_with_django_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: django

I've been going through the Tango With Django 1.7 guide and I've come up with the following issue that I'm having troubles fixing:

```
Using the URLconf defined in tango_with_django_project.urls, Django 
tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. ^$ [name='index']
2. ^about/$ [name='about']
3. ^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$ [name='category']
4. ^admin/
5. ^rango/$
6. ^about/
7. ^category/
8. ^media/(?P<path>.*)
The current URL, rango/category/python, didn't match any of these.
```

This is my rango/urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns(' ',
                   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                   url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
                   url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 
views.category, name='category')
                   )
```

In tango_with_django_project/urls.py I have

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rango import views

from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                   url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^rango/$', include('rango.urls')),
url(r'^about/', include('rango.urls')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns+= patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

In rango/views.py I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rango.models import Category
from rango.models import Page

def index(request):

category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)


def about(request):
return HttpResponse("Rango says: Hello world! <br/> <a             
href='/rango/about'>About</a>")


def category(request, category_name_slug):

context_dict = {}

try:

    category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    context_dict['category_name'] = category.name

    pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

    context_dict['pages'] = pages

    context_dict['category'] = category
except Category.DoesNotExist:

return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)
```

I've been following the guide so I'm not quite sure what the problem is; I had a similar problem earlier on in the guide when I was getting the same error but with /about (never got this fixed).
Any idea what might be causing this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In `tango_with_django_project/urls.py` try changing `url(r'^rango/$', include('rango.urls'))` to `url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls'))`. The `$` signals end-of-string which you probably don't want.

Comment: @ascripter I can't thank you enough, that fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, the problem here is the definition of the URLconf, more precisely the [inclusion of another URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/) that shall define every url that starts with `rango/...`. The crucial line is this one:

```
url(r'^rango/$', include('rango.urls')),
```

which should read instead

```
url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
```

The [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `'^rango/$'` captures: `<start-of-string>rango/<end-of-string>`

The regex `'^rango/'` captures: `<start-of-string>rango/<whatever follows>`, and that's where your included urls kick in.